# "Grab me from my arm" vs "Grab my arm"

Tags: word-choice, idioms, prepositions

What is the difference between saying the following two:

> She grabbed *my arm* and walked me to the car.
>
> She grabbed *me from my arm* and walked me to the car.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first is saying that she took hold of your arm and directed you to your car.

The second sounds as though she removed the rest of your body and walked you to the car, minus a limb.

You could say that *she grabbed me by the arm* instead of *from my arm.*

Comment: Does it still mean the same thing as the first one if we say: she grabbed me by the arm and walked me to the car.

Comment: @noah - yes, grabbed my arm, grabbed me by the arm, mean pretty much the same thing

Comment: @mgb - except that grabbed me by the arm implies that the arm is still attached to me, while grabbed my arm could theoretically mean that [he] grabbed my unattached arm [from the table] :)

Comment: The difference is much clearer between "she grabbed me by my coat and walked me to the car" and "she grabbed my coat and walked me to the car". In the first, I am clearly wearing the coat. In the second, I may not be. And "she grabbed me from my coat" sounds like I had been wearing the coat, but she pulled me out of it.

Comment: @PeterShor, of course the arm may have nothing do with me. I might be in a museum with the missing bits of the Venus de Milo and she grabbed me near one them and took me to the car.  Although this is still better than being hung up by the Jackson Pollocks